# Nested master pages using Razor syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, master-pages

I'm trying to get nested master pages working with the new razor syntax.  Any help appreciated:

The error I'm getting is

```
Execute() no suitable method found to override
```

Delving further I have my _Site.cshtml, which is the main master page and inherits ViewMasterPage.

My nested master page is _layout.cshtml, which uses _site as a layout, uses some helpers and inherits from ViewMasterPage

I have a _ViewStart.cshtml, which points to my Layout file.

And finally I have my index page which inherits from ViewPage

So at the top of each page I have:

**Site:**

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage
```

**Layout**

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage<MyMasterViewModel>
@{ Layout ="~/Views/Shared/_Site.cshtml"; }
```

**ViewStart**

```
@{ Layout ="~/Areas/AreaName/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }
```

**Index**

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyHomeModel>
```

Any ideas???

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewMasterPage` is used for WebForms views.
Razor layout pages do not inherit a special class; instead, they inherit the same `ViewPage` class.

You should use the `@model` directive instead of `@inherits` in all three pages.

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone else facing the same issue.  Remove the line in the Site master page, change Layout to @model MyMasterViewModel and Index to @model MyHomeModel.